# DiceSum - How to extend if/ if-else statement to reroll dice if dice sum is not a certain number

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int n;
  int win = 0;
  int lose = 0;
  int dice1;
  int dice2;
  int diceSum;

  srand(time(0));

  cout << "How many turns would you like? ";
        cin >> n;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
      dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
      dice2 = rand()%6 + 1;
      diceSum = dice1 + dice2;

    if((diceSum == 2) || (diceSum == 3) || (diceSum == 12)){
      win++;
    }
    else if((diceSum == 7) || (diceSum == 11)){
      lose++;
    }
    else{

    }
  }
  cout << "No. of Wins: " << win << endl;
  cout << "No. of Losses: " << lose << endl;
  cout<< setprecision(4)<<fixed<<showpoint;
  cout << "\nThe experimental probability of winning "<< (static_cast<float>(win)/n)*100 <<
  "%.\n";
  return 0;
}
```

My assignments states that "...can be shown analytically that the long term probability of winning the dice game you have programmed in PA 8-3 is .4929293. Extend that program you wrote to run a large number of turns and calculate the empirical (experimental) probability." My last assignment I had to make a program to roll two die and reveal the dice sum. If it was a 2, 3, or 12, I won; if it was a 7 or 11 it was a loss, otherwise it would repeat the roll. I was unable to repeat the roll, now for this assignment, I have to do the same thing.[This is my output from my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh4JL.png)

Comment: Wrap a do/while loop around your roll code. Better yet, make it a function. The condition for the while is that you did not win or lose.

Comment: Just for fun, replace `rand` with a [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) see how much closer to 50/50 you can get.

Comment: I feel like you've described the assignment incorrectly. Implementing it as you've described you win ~33.3% of the time. Assuming it was meant to mimic Craps the numbers you have listed for win and loss are reversed and you're missing the point concept.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to not take into account the cases where the *sum* is not 2,3,12,7 or 11 you have lot of possibilities, for instance :

- closer to your code do `i -=1;` in the empty `else {}`

  ```
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand()%6 + 1;
    diceSum = dice1 + dice2;

    if((diceSum == 2) || (diceSum == 3) || (diceSum == 12)){
      win++;
    }
    else if((diceSum == 7) || (diceSum == 11)){
      lose++;
    }
    else{
      i -= 1;
    }
  }
  ```
- or increment *i* only when you win or lose and remove `i++` in the `for()`

  ```
  for (int i = 1; i <= n;)
  {
    dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand()%6 + 1;
    diceSum = dice1 + dice2;

    if((diceSum == 2) || (diceSum == 3) || (diceSum == 12)){
      win++;
      i++;
    }
    else if((diceSum == 7) || (diceSum == 11)){
      lose++;
      i++;
    }
  }
  ```
- or the variant

  ```
  i = n;
  for (;;)
  {
    dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand()%6 + 1;
    diceSum = dice1 + dice2;

    if((diceSum == 2) || (diceSum == 3) || (diceSum == 12)){
      win++;
      if (!--i)
        break;
    }
    else if((diceSum == 7) || (diceSum == 11)){
      lose++;
      if (!--i)
        break;
    }
  }
  ```
- or remove all about *i* and replace your *for* by `do { dice1 = ..... } while ((win + lose) != n);` without having the last *else* branch

  ```
  do {
    dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand()%6 + 1;
    diceSum = dice1 + dice2;

    if((diceSum == 2) || (diceSum == 3) || (diceSum == 12)){
      win++;
    }
    else if((diceSum == 7) || (diceSum == 11)){
      lose++;
    }
  } while ((win + lose) != n);
  ```
- or the variant

  ```
  for (;;) {
    dice1 = rand()%6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand()%6 + 1;
    diceSum = dice1 + dice2;

    if((diceSum == 2) || (diceSum == 3) || (diceSum == 12)){
      if ((++win + lose) == n)
        break;
    }
    else if((diceSum == 7) || (diceSum == 11)){
      if ((++lose + win) == n)
        break;
    }
  }
  ```

Example of execution whatever the way :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
How many turns would you like? 1000
No. of Wins: 336
No. of Losses: 664

The experimental probability of winning 33.6000%.
```

This result it normal even it seems opposite of the intuition because the possibilities to make these numbers are :

- 2 : 1+1
- 3 : 1+2 2+1
- 12 : 6+6

and

- 7: 1+6 6+1 2+5 5+2 3+4 4+3
- 11 : 5+6 6+5

so 4 possibilities to win ( 1/3/12 ) and 8 possibilities to lose ( 7/11 ), so the probability to lose if two times more than the probability to win

---

I encourage you to always check the input, replacing

> ```
> cin >> n;
> ```

by something like

```
if (!(cin >> n)) {
  cerr << "invalid number" << endl;
  return -1;
}
```